# What is the difference between recursion and iteration?

Tags: recursion, iteration

I am searching for the difference between recursion and iteration in java. Please include a Java code example of both.

2.How can i open my open application only if i receive message in android?

1. How to close the third party services that running in the device?

Comment: @John why you edit my question i didn't get the answer yet

Comment: I think the description on my edit explains why I did it. "Clean up question to be objective rather than ask what is better." I did also take your request for a code snippet out of the title. I should have moved it into the content of the question. Fixed that. As for why I edited it when you didn't get the answer yet. I edited it in the hopes that you will get a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion happens when a method or function calls itself on a subset of its original argument. For example, MergeSort - it splits the array into two halves and calls itself on these two halves.

Recursion would look like this, but it is a very artificial example that works similarly to the iteration example below:

```
public void doSomething(int i) {
    // code
    if (i == 10) {
        return;
    } else {
        doSomething(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Iteration is one pass of a cycle or loop. For example, code in this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //code
}
```

will be executed 10 times, i.e. have 10 iterations.

Comment: Can u give example of recursion any code snippet

Comment: I am on mobile, hard to type code for me right now. Search for MergeSort on internet.

Comment: @ Jakub Zaverka can we say that when we don't know the condition in advance then we use recursion and vice versa for iteration.