# Recusion to print integer in reverse order

Tags: java, recursion, integer

I am just learning recursion and I am to print an input array in reverse order (without using any String or Character methods).

For example `4295` would be displayed as `5924`.

```
public static void method_c(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.println(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
```

have this code but it only returns the `5`, so I'm guessing its not going back through doing the recursion. I thought that it may be the placement of `n /= 10`, but that only changed the number that was returned.

How would I fix it to go back through to print the whole integer?

Comment: Note that this isn't recursion, just a loop.  If you wanted to do this recursively, you would have to call the method inside of itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basic of recursion is to call the same method again from inside and that is missing.

```
public static void method_c(int n) 
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        System.out.print(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
        method_c(n);
    }
}
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Don't work with minus...         number 292:292        number 34:43        number -292:        number -18:        number -334:        number -165:        number 288:882        number -405:        number 100:001        number -383:        number -467:        number 449:944        number 429:924        number -55:        number -33:

Comment: @barwnikk, i don't think the solution is expected to work the way you suggested for negative numbers. When you reverse the numbers, definitely the position of '-' shouldn't change.
This is a clear and proper answer and my +1 for it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out: In order to make your method work, change your `if` to a `while`:

```
public static void method_c(int n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        System.out.println(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
}
```

Judging from your description, there seems to be an important misconception here though: What you are doing is an **iteration** and **NOT a recursion**. For a quick glimpse at the differences between iteration and recursion, look, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305050/what-is-the-difference-between-recursion-and-iteration).

Comment: Don't work with minus...         number 292:292        number 34:43        number -292:        number -18:        number -334:        number -165:        number 288:882        number -405:        number 100:001        number -383:        number -467:        number 449:944        number 429:924        number -55:        number -33:

Comment: That's because you missed the point of the question and didn't do it with recursion. Look at the answer actually marked correct... seperately what does your answer add that hasn't already been said?

Answer (score 1):

For recursion, you are forgetting that you have to call the method inside of itself except in a base case, so you would want:

```
public static void method_c(int n) {
    if (n != 0) {
        Boolean negative = false;    
        if (n<0) {
            n*=-1;
            negative = true;
        }        
        System.out.print(n % 10);
        method_c(n/10);
        if (negative) System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

Calling method_c on n/10 except when n is 0 will make the function recursive.

Comment: Ehhh... Don't work with minus...         number 292:292        number 34:43        number -292:        number -18:        number -334:        number -165:        number 288:882        number -405:        number 100:001        number -383:        number -467:        number 449:944        number 429:924        number -55:        number -33:

Comment: It was because of your case `if (n>0)`. I changed the recursive code to take account negative and print the minus sign at the end.

Comment: You can also have it print the minus sign at the front by moving the last line up if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**It's working with a minus number!!!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        int number = (int) (System.nanoTime()%1000)-500; //random number
        System.out.println(number+" - "+method_c(number)); //printing
    }
}
public static int method_c(int number) {
    String output = number<0?"-":"";
    if(number<0)number=-number;
    while (number > 0) {
        output += number % 10 + "";
        number /= 10;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(output);
}
```

Sample output:

```
73 - 37
120 - 21
-395 - -593
216 - 612
-78 - -87
... more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `if` to a `while` would achieve the desired result but it would be iterative, not recursive. A recursive method would call itself, after checking that a base stopping condition is met. You would probably want to write something like:

```
public static void method_c(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.println(n % 10);
        method_c(n / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work with minus...         number 292:292        number 34:43        number -292:        number -18:        number -334:        number -165:        number 288:882        number -405:        number 100:001        number -383:        number -467:        number 449:944        number 429:924        number -55:        number -33: